# root shell bash commands not working

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, root, passwd

I attempted to change my sudo password(I removed myself from sudoers list by mistake). I tried following.

1. In recovery mode, I dropped down to root shell. It is still asking root password. Ctrl D did not work. I went to generic `e` mode then.
2. I replaced `ro quite splash` with `rw init=/bin/bash` and pressed F10 to enter in to root shell.

   ```
   root@nouser$ passwd vasu  
   bash : passwd command not found  
   root@nouser$ sudo passwd vasu  
   bash : sudo command not found
   ```

I know commands like sudo and passwd are in `/usr/bin`.
But I found `/usr` folder to be empty. 
`ls /home` is empty as well .
But infact I have three users in home folder.
I can execute `passwd` command in general boot.  (of course, It is telling I can't do that).
Can some one tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `mount -o remount,rw /`?

Comment: did you use mount -a to well mount the tings that are listed in fstab?

Comment: 16 sec faster :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount /usr
/usr/bin/passwd root

reboot
```

where

- you need to mount `/` with `rw` to mount `/usr`
- you need `/usr` for `passwd` command.